# Translation handling in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am building a multi-lingual application with Zend Framework 2.

Currently, I have every object with a translatable output implement the TranslatorAwareInterface and use the TranslatorAwareTrait. So, I'am injecting a translator instance into every form, input filter and controller object in order to translate form labels, error messages and notifications.

Is this the correct way to do it or is there a different approach which does not require to inject a translator instance into every object having a text needing a translation?

(I know I can translate validation errors by injecting a default translator to AbstractValidator, but I prefer to have my own error messages)

Comment: All in all i'd say it sounds legit

Comment: Manu, you can pass your own `messageTemplates` array keyed by the validators error code in validator options. There's no need to handle it in your forms or views directly.

Comment: @Crisp Thank you for the hint. That's the solution for customer validation errors. What about translating form element labels and messages generated in controllers and other objects, e.g. entities?

Comment: For other objects I'd say the way you're doing it is the way to go. Auto translation of form element labels and titles would be a nice feature, but as far as I can tell it isn't implemented.

Comment: @Crisp Thanks, I feel much more comfortable now :-) and will go on that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use doctrine module for zf2 as orm and let Doctrine extension gedmo/translatable handle the data translation https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions

To get the Translatable feature working, follow this part of the documentation:
https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/zendframework2.md#note-you-may-need-to-provide-additional-settings-for-some-of-the-available-listeners

After that run the schema tool to update your database.

Comment: I do not know that extension, but I cannot see how that would help translating form element labels and messages generated in controllers?

Comment: i suggest that for translating model  ... messages and form elements are translated easily via zend_i18n/translate

Comment: What about systems with DB2 on iSeries. Doctrine won't work there. Within ZF2 translatable is imo a missing feature.